# Generator for cyclic group

Tags: group-theory

$K = \left\{ ak + bh | k,h \in \mathbb{Z} \right\}$ is a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}$, and thus it is a cyclic group.  Since $K$ is a cyclic group it must have a generator $g$ for which $g^{n}$ can generate every element in $K$.  Would the generator for $K$ be $\gcd(a,b)$ (the greatest common divisor of $a$ and $b$)?  I think it should because you can simply add $\gcd(a,b)$ $n$ times to get every element in $K$?  Is this correct?

Comment: Consider the least positive element of $K$ and use the division algorithm to prove it divides every other element of $K$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your group is $a\Bbb{Z}+b\Bbb{Z}.$ If a and b are relatively prime, then $a\Bbb{Z}+b\Bbb{Z}=\Bbb{Z}$ which is generated by 1. Otherwise, let d = (a,b). Then $d(\frac ad\Bbb{Z}+\frac bd\Bbb{Z})=d\Bbb{Z}$. which is generated by d. So your reasoning was correct, the group in question is generated by (a,b).

Comment: If a and b are relatively prime why would aZ + bZ = Z?  For example, a = 5 and b = 6 are relatively prime.  but 5Z + 6Z  = {..., -6, -5, 0, 5, 6, 10, 12, 15, ...} which does not equal Z.

Comment: Actually I think I know what you were saying.  if a and b are relatively prime then ak + bh can form every element in Z, but if they are not relatively prime then ak + bh = gcd(a,b)(m) where m is any integer.

Comment: @MomoTheSir check the other answer for more clarification on why the sum of aZ + bZ = Z if a and b are relatively prime.

Answer (score 1):

Say $a$ and $b$ were coprime, then $\gcd(a,b)=1$, and by Bezout's Theorem you can find $k,h\in\Bbb{Z}$ s.t. 
$$ak+bh=1\tag{1}$$ 
Then you can generate all of $\Bbb{Z}$ by simply multiplying (1) by any integer, $m$ say, then 
$$amk+bmh=m\tag{2}$$
Of course if $\gcd(a,b)=d$, where $d\neq1$ then the subgroup would be $d\Bbb{Z}$, and consist of all multiples of $d$ in the same way if $a$ and $b$ were coprime they would generate all multiples of $1$.

Comment: No problem, you were correct in your initial thoughts on the matter. Cheers, Dan